# add number before dates on visual studio

Tags: sql, t-sql, visual-studio-2008

Hi guys I have this code here where outputs two column, 1 column is 1-30 and the other 1 is 30 days before today.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date

SELECT @StartDate = GETDATE()

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
              1 AS idx,
               DATEADD(d,-1,@StartDate) AS idxDate
UNION ALL
SELECT idx -1, DATEADD(d,-1,idxDate)
FROM cte
WHERE idx >-30
)
    SELECT idx DateValue, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),idxDate,110) DateLabel
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

It looks like this currently

```
 DateValue   DateLabel
1            06-20-2013
0            06-19-2013
-1           06-18-2013
-2           06-17-2013
etc....
```

so instead of 1 and 0 in the beginning it should be -1 and I want to add the dateavalue in front of behind the datelabel to look like this:

```
 DateValue   DateLabel
-1            06-20-2013, -1
-2            06-19-2013, -2
-3            06-18-2013, -3
-4            06-17-2013, -4
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date

SELECT @StartDate = GETDATE();

WITH cte AS 
(
     SELECT -1 AS idx, DATEADD(d,-1,@StartDate) AS idxDate
     UNION ALL
     SELECT idx -1, DATEADD(d,-1,idxDate)
     FROM cte
     WHERE idx >-30
)

SELECT idx DateValue, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),idxDate,110) + ', ' + CAST(idx as nvarchar(max)) DateLabel
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: o yes! thank you so much! wish i could vote it but needs 15 repts ;(

Answer (score 0):

add

```
order by DateValue desc
```

to the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can just tweak your last `SELECT` a bit:

```
  SELECT idx-2 AS DateValue, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),idxDate,110) +', ' + CAST(idx-2 AS NVARCHAR(10)) DateLabel
FROM CTE
```